# RestKit 0.23.1 one to many relationship mapping not working

Tags: json, core-data, relationship, fault

I have been struggling with figuring out how to map this JSON data to a managed object in Core Data using RestKit 0.23.1 for the past several days. My data contains multiple "objects", each of which has its own list of one or more "links" which are structured objects containing preview information for URLs:

```
objects": [

{
    "id": "03fbbec709d261c87a64d979fe1e530b",
    "object_type": "note",
    "links": [
    {
        "id": "d48066cf6daa007e31f8915831f46fc2",
        "urlSite": "techcrunch.com",
        "siteName": null,
        "urlString": "http://techcrunch.com/2014/06/16/secret-finally-lets-all-your-freaky-friends-have-their-own-feed/",
        "urlShortened": "http://gcq.me/1vzsVJY",
        "title": "Secret Finally Lets All Your Freaky Friends Have Their Own Feeds | TechCrunch",
        "previewImage": "http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/secret2.jpg?w=650",
        "previewText": "Secret Finally Lets All Your Freaky Friends Have Their Own Feeds | TechCrunch",
        "lastUpdated": "2014-06-17 06:50:56",
        "lastVisited": "2014-06-17 06:50:56",
        "visitCount": 0
    }

    ]
}]
```

I've created functions to help build out my mapping relationships:

```
+ (RKEntityMapping*)webLinkMapping {
RKManagedObjectStore* managedObjectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore];
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"WebLink" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

mapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"objectId" ];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"id": @"objectId"}];

[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"urlSite", @"siteName", @"urlString", @"urlShortened",
                                          @"title", @"previewImage", @"previewText", @"lastUpdated",
                                          @"lastVisited", @"visitCount"]];

return mapping;
}

+ (RKEntityMapping*)streamObjectMapping {
RKManagedObjectStore* managedObjectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore];
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"StreamObject" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
mapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"objectId" ];

[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"id":                      @"objectId",
}];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"object_type"]];

[mapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"links" mapping:[self webLinkMapping]];
//[mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"links" toKeyPath:@"links" withMapping:[self webLinkMapping]]];

return mapping;
}
```

I'm almost certain it's the pair of square brackets around the array of links being returned in the JSON that is causing my mappings not to work right.  I keep getting relationship faults in my returned stream objects:

```
links = "<relationship fault: 0x114a05820 'links'>";
```

Looking at the actual data tables using a sqlite browser, I'm seeing my links objects are being stored with the correct associated objectId from the parent object, so they're just not being returned correctly when I ask for my stream object.  Any thoughts on how I correct this?

Regarding loading into memory, it doesn't appear to be doing so:

```
RKStreamObject* postObject = [_postObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSLog(@"Links: %@", postObject.links);


2014-06-20 11:25:11.249 MyApp[6026:151920] Links: Relationship 'links' fault on managed object (0x110c47ee0) <RKStreamObject: 0x110c47ee0> (entity: StreamObject; id: 0xd000000001000000 <x-coredata://F96BC470-82A5-4C56-81A9-71C6129F967B/StreamObject/p64> ; data: {
body = "http://techcrunch.com/2014/06/16/secret-finally-lets-all-your-freaky-friends-have-their-own-feed/";
"comment_count" = 0;
controllerSource = nil;
"gc_updated" = "2014-06-20 16:25:10 +0000";
"liked_by_me" = 0;
likes = 0;
links = "<relationship fault: 0x1141bce40 'links'>";
objectId = 03fbbec709d261c87a64d979fe1e530b;
"object_type" = note;
photo = nil;
"photo_feed" = nil;
"photo_height" = 0;
"photo_width" = 0;
place = "0xd000000000100002 <x-coredata://F96BC470-82A5-4C56-81A9-71C6129F967B/Place/p4>";
privacy = F;
"subscribed_by_me" = 1;
timestamp = "2014-06-17T06:51:00-05:00";
"timestamp_as_words" = "3 days ago";
"timestamp_formatted" = "Tuesday, June 17, 2014 at 06:51:00 CDT";
"timestamp_unix" = 1403005860;
user = "0xd0000000000c0004 <x-coredata://F96BC470-82A5-4C56-81A9-71C6129F967B/User/p3>";
videoId = nil;
videoSource = nil;
})
```

Notice how "place" and "user" show up ok?  These are 1-to-1 object mappings that work fine. Shouldn't links come up when I call them directly as in the NSLog statement?

Final edit, per Wain's suggestion, I pulled the first object from the relationship's array and it returns the related web link.

```
if ([postObject.links count] > 0) {
    RKWebLink *link = [[postObject.links allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Link title: %@", link.title);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
links = "<relationship fault: 0x114a05820 'links'>";
```

This doesn't mean that the relationship content doesn't exist, it simply means that it hasn't been loaded into memory yet (this is a fault). When you try to use the relationship contents it will be loaded.

Your code looks fine. The square brackets just mean that you have an array / list of objects instead of one and is not a problem (it's a good thing).

Comment: Based on other similar threads and this same response, I'd tend to agree with you, except that when I do access the links variable, I still get the same fault.  I added more information to the post to show how I'm attempting to access links.

Comment: Extract the first item from the relationship and log it. Faults are fired sparingly so as much as possible won't fire and load the data.

Comment: You, sir, are a lifesaver! I never (well, maybe eventually) would have thought to try that. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!!